# There's just a lot going on right now

Tags: existentials

> a. There's (just) a lot going on right now.

Without 'just', I think (a) means

> b. "A lot is going on right now"

rather than

> c. "A lot that's going on exists right now".

Right?

Now, if we add 'just' back in (a), where do we put 'just' in (b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(c) doesn't make any sense to me. (a) only works in the sense "The only thing is, there is a lot going on right now"  (as an excuse for being too busy to do something).

I differ from DialFrost in thinking that *just* here means 'simply, only' rather than 'recently'.

Comment: Thanks. So you can't really put 'just' in (b)?

Comment: No, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks. The only way I can think of is _It's just that a lot is going on right now_. Of course, this is adding more than just _just_, but does this convey the same meaning?

Comment: I would consider that the most natural way of expressing it.